# Why is cin used as a loop condition?

Tags: c++

In my c++ book, there is this loop:

```
vector<double> temps; // temperatures
for (double temp; cin>>temp; ) // read and put into temps
    temps.push_back(temp);
```

This appears to loop forever. I can't stop this loop. What purpose does this serve?

Comment: I edited your question pretty heavily to try to make it clearer. If you disagree with the edit, feel free to change it back.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `operator>>` will return the stream (`cin`) which itself can be converted to a `bool` that represents if the stream is still valid or not. That will loop until something causes `cin`'s read to fail (end of file, a letters instead of numbers, etc).

Answer (score 0):

This is similar to:

```
 int num;
  while(cin.good())  //could also use while(cin)
  {
      cin >> num;
      cout << num << endl;
  }
```

Where you continuously read a number and print it. Inputting a non-number causes the input stream to fail hence cin.good() becomes false.(stream is good no more)